# Safari browser JS error with Google customer reviews

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, content-security-policy, merchant-account

So I have implemented the Google customer-reviews badge on a site and it’s throwing a JS error in the devtools console:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'base-uri'
```

Anyone encountered this error before and know how to resolve it?

The customer-reviews badge was implemented using the code supplied in the Google merchant center.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderBadge" async defer></script>
<script>
    window.renderBadge = function () {
        var ratingBadgeContainer = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(ratingBadgeContainer);
        window.gapi.load('ratingbadge', function () {
            window.gapi.ratingbadge.render(ratingBadgeContainer, { "merchant_id": MERCHANT_ID, "position": "BOTTOM_RIGHT" });
        });
    }
</script>
<script>
    window.___gcfg = {
        lang: 'en_US'
    };
</script>
```

In IIS this is  what I have for access control policy:

```
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
  <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
```

If I try to add the following I get a large amount of errors in the dev tools:

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy"
  value="script-src 'self' apis.google.com api.addressy.com maps.googleapis.com
  cdn.jsdelivr.net code.jquery.com www.googletagmanager.com;" />
```

This is one of the errors:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“script-src https://mydomain.com.au
>   https://apis.google.com https://api.addressy.com
>   https://maps.googleapis.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net
>   https://code.jquery.com https://www.googletagmanager.com”). Source:
>   onchange attribute on DIV element.

UPDATE

> UPDATED WORKAROUND So as I can't resolve this problem I have just come
>   up with a workaround. As the error was stopping other javascript from
>   running(which executed after error thrown) I have moved the google
>   customer reviews code to the very bottom of the page. So it's the very
>   last bit of javascript to run. This way it doesn't matter if it's
>   giving a error as the site will still function.

Also I check if the browser is safari and if it is I don't render the badge.
This is not an ideal solution as now the badge is missing from safari browsers but it's the best I got until I figure it out.

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

window.renderBadge = function () {
    if (!isSafari) {
        var ratingBadgeContainer = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(ratingBadgeContainer);
        window.gapi.load('ratingbadge', function () {
            window.gapi.ratingbadge.render(ratingBadgeContainer, { "merchant_id": MERCHANT_ID, "position": "BOTTOM_RIGHT" });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: so ... what does your content-security-policy look like?

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi thanks for the help. Hmm don't have one as far as I'm aware. Working with a site someone else built. Where would I find it. its a customized version of nopcommrce, built from the source code

Comment: either in the HTTP headers or as a html `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...` tag

Comment: in html all I have is this `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>`
Can't find anything in the headers for it.

Comment: `in http` - that looks like HTML ... http headers don't look like that - anyway, any indication in the developer tools console where the CSP comes from?

Comment: sorry typo, nah in the http headers there is nothing about csp.
Im looking at the first request on the network tab which is the `/`

Comment: There is this which is the only thing which remotely looks like it might be related to CSP. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: It’s loading a `https://www.google.com/shopping/customerreviews/badge…` URL in an iframe, and that document is served the CSP header `script-src 'unsafe-inline' https: http: 'unsafe-eval';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /_/VerifiedReviewsBadgeUi/cspreport`, which is a valid CSP policy. And Safari supports `base-uri`. So dunno why that message appears

Comment: nope, that's a CORS header, nothing to do with CSP

Comment: what version of Safari?

Comment: If that has nothing to do with your server, not much you can do

Comment: It was the latest version on ipads and iphones, damn I gotta leave the office :/ still new so can't stick around.
Will be home in a few hours

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated my question and added the current security policy